# Testing htaccess file with 500 server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server-error

After reading some tutorials, I have created an error file, that should be displayed instead of 500 server error. I have added it to domain's root and added the following line to the bottom of `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html
```

Now the question is, how can I test it on a live site and make sure that the error page appears, when site really crashes?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can place this snippet in your .htaccess:

```
# 500 handler
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html

# causing 500
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .foo
```

Also create a file with some random chars like `abc.foo` in your site root:

```
cat abc.foo
asdf
```

Now send a request to `abc.foo` as `http://domain.com/abc.foo`, and it will generate 500 and show your `error.html`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I have added it, but if I send a request to any `.foo` I am just given an 404 error.

Comment: Sorry I missed out file creation of `abc.foo` with random text. Please check updated answer now